# Ansible: pvchange with shell does not get executed

Tags: shell, ansible

I'm not able to execute the shell command pvchange -u /dev/sde with ansible.
Can you pls help me to figure out what's wrong?

```
  vars:  
    tgt_string_id: TGTDBID  
    action_vg: "clone_{{ tgt_string_id }}vg"  
    host_vars_dir: /home/abhn02a/ansible/host_vars  
    action_host: "{{ tgt_vm | default('localhost') }}"  
    tgt_disks: "/dev/sde /dev/sdf"
```

### Tasks

```
    - name: Display target disks
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ tgt_disks.split(' ') }}"

    - name: Change pv uuid
      become: yes
      shell: |
        pvchange -u "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ tgt_disks.split(' ') }}"
      #changed_when: false
      delegate_to: "{{ action_host }}"
```

### Output:

```
......  
.......  
TASK [Display target disks]  
*********************************************************************************************  
ok: [localhost] => (item=/dev/sde) => {  
    "msg": "/dev/sde"  
}  
ok: [localhost] => (item=/dev/sdf) => {  
    "msg": "/dev/sdf"  
}  

!! This is not true, uuid stays same !!!  
TASK [Change pv uuid]  

***************************************************************************************************  
changed: [localhost] => (item=/dev/sde)  
changed: [localhost] => (item=/dev/sdf)  
.......  
.....
```

When I check the uuid of the disk, It has not been changed. Then, I type "pvchange -u /dev/sde", It changes the uuid of the disk with no problem!
Have ansible 2.9 with python2.7.5
Can you help, please?
(Oh, this is my 1st question on SO, sorry for the previous formatting)

### Edit

So I have almost reproduced the error at home.
This happens when I try to do a pvchange on a cloned disk (But again, only with Ansible!!)
I have cloned 2 disks (/dev/xvdc and /dev/xvde) to (/dev/xvdf and /dev/xvdg), and re-run the task, and I have following output:

```
TASK [Change pv uuid]  
*************************************************************************  
failed: [localhost] (item=/dev/xvdf) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "pvchange -u \"/dev/xvdf\"\n", "delta": "0:00:00.038053", "end": "2021-03-06 03:46:07.526239", "item": "/dev/xvdf", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 5, "start": "2021-03-06 03:46:07.488186", "stderr": "  Failed to find physical volume \"/dev/xvdf\".", "stderr_lines": ["  Failed to find physical volume \"/dev/xvdf\"."], "stdout": "  0 physical volumes changed / 0 physical volumes not changed", "stdout_lines": ["  0 physical volumes changed / 0 physical volumes not changed"]}
```

This seems to be, because the cloned disks are still not "PVs" in LVM; I do not see /dev/xvdf and /dev/xvdg when I do pvs.
But at work, this was different, I could see the cloned disks in "pvs output"
Will check again next week.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, nimgeneva, welcome to SO. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66500664/edit) and fix the formatting

Comment: Can you `register` the "change pv uuid" task in a variable and then `debug` it? you will get the stdout and stderr of the command execution. The return code may be 0 (meaning command was successful) but there may be some message issued on stdxxx explaining that nothing was done for some reason.

Comment: Hi @zigarn Thanks for your idea. I'll test this in my working environment next Thursday; Meanwhile I've tested this on a different centos server, and all work well! There should be something wrong in the working environment. Will keep you updated.

Comment: Remove the quotes: `pvchange -u {{ item }}`. The error message is saying that `"/dev/xvdf"` does not exist, because the device name is `/dev/xvdf` (without quotes). (I was suspecting this in the first place but wanted message for confirmation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pvscan --cache `, before doing` pvchange -u <PV>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the dub of the execution, you can see that the command executed is `pvchange -u "/dev/xvdf"`, which raise an error message '`Failed to find physical volume "/dev/xvdf".`', so looks like it doesn't like the quotes.

You can change your task to that, it should works better:

```yaml
    - name: Change pv uuid
      become: yes
      shell: |
        pvchange -u {{ item }}
      loop: "{{ tgt_disks.split(' ') }}"
```

Comment: Bonjour  Zigarn,  Yes indeed you are correct.  However, there were 2 problems;   1st thing is quotes;   Then even after I removed it, The OS is doing nothing;   Tried without Ansible same result, pvchange -u does not change anything, but it says "0 physical volumes changed / 0 physical volumes not changed" With many other warnings, however RC=0. I'm on RedHat 7.9 don't know if this is a bug. Anyway, the pb. is not Ansible, but OS behaviour.  So, Thank you very much for double hint!

Comment: Just FYI : Somehow, I needed to add a task to do pvscan --cache , before doing pvchange -u <PV>; Otherwise the duplicated PVs are ignored